# webkit2gtk-4.0 script_message_received does not work vala

Tags: javascript, gtk, vala, webkit2

I am creating a WebKit WebView from Vala.

I connected the UserContentManager and registered a script message handler.

I also connected the script_message_received signal before that, as it is writte in the Valadoc documentation.

The script was successfully registered, but `script_message_received` does not fire. After executing the script

```
window.webkit.messageHandlers.test.postMessage ('test');
```

Nothing happens.

```
WebView webKit = new WebView ();

webKit = new WebView.with_user_content_manager (new WebKit.UserContentManager ());

webKit.user_content_manager.script_message_received.connect ((js_result) =>
{
    debug ("Test result");
});

if (! webKit.user_content_manager.register_script_message_handler ("test"))
    debug ("Failed to register script message handler");
```

What do I have to do so that the signal is fired?

Comment: I have heavily edited you question to make it easier to understand, I hope I got it all correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in `public class Main: Object`

You need to use `public class Main: Gtk.Window`

Otherwise nothing works.

Comment: You might want to elaborate here especially as there is no mention of a class declaration in your question